# Importing percentage value in Salesforce through Talend

Tags: salesforce, talend

I am trying to upload data in Salesforce using Talend, however for a Percent it fails:

```
Exception in component tSalesforceOutput_2
java.io.IOException: Error Chance: value not of required type: 6.15
```

Salesforce Talend component is suggesting the field should be a float as on output, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the value to 0.0615 (percent fields like to be in the 0.0 to 1.0 range)

Comment: That was the original value I had, I tried to multiply by 100 to make it work but with no luck